# BottomNavigationView Title Position SDK 31

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I just upgraded the target and compile sdk of my Android project from 30 to 31 and the title in my bottomnavigationview has moved from below the icon to above it.

SDK 30:

[image: SDK30]

SDK 31:

[image: SDK31]

How can I get he title back to its position below the icon?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Please share the related XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sujal. I took a look at my xml and found this to be the problem:

`android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"`

After removing this, the labels are at the bottom again.